# Get Google AuthSub token from android app

Tags: android, token, google-api-java-client, authsub

I'm writing an android program which must interact with google documents, so I have watched [this](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/docs-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/docs/cmdline/DocsSample.java?repo=samples&r=3702d857761f7caae83306a9016f73d5c1fc01f1) sample, but it uses an AuthSub token. How can I get an AuthSub Token from an android app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For accessing Google Docs or any other Google service (or any OAuth based service for that matter) you will need to find a way to do an OAuth based authentication, after which you can u get a secure token which you can use to access a service based on the users credentials.

There are some really good examples to get you started:

- This is an example of getting AccountManager to work with a Google
  service like Google Tasks, this shows you how to generate tokens and
  then how to use them:
  https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/oauth-and-tasks-on-android
- This is an in-depth look into how you can authenticate based on the
  users Android credentials, has an example of how things work and how
  the UI should be:
  http://www.finalconcept.com.au/article/view/android-account-manager-step-by-step-2

For something specific to Google Docs have a look at

- http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Android
- http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/trunk/java/sample/docs/DocumentResumableUploadDemo.java